# How to join elements inside a tuple, in list of tuples?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list like

```
A = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (3, 5, 7)]
```

and I want to turn it into

```
A = [[123], [345], [357]]
```

Is there any way to do this?

My upper list with tuple comes from permutation function so maybe you can reccomend me to change something in that code

```
def converter(N):
    y = list(str(N))
    t = [int(x) for x in y]
    f = list(itertools.permutations(t))
    return f

r = converter(345)
print(r)
```

Comment: So you want to concatenate elements of every tuple like string?

Comment: Are those decimal integers `123` and so on? Or are they supposed to be lists `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: and do the elements have to be integers, or can they be strings too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can swizzle that up like so:

#### Code:

```
[[int(''.join(str(i) for i in x))] for x in a]
```

this converts the integer digits to a str, and then joins them before converting back to an integer.

#### Test Code:

```
a = [(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (3, 5, 7)]
print([[int(''.join(str(i) for i in x))] for x in a])
```

#### Results:

```
[[123], [345], [357]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun (and for proving a radically different approach):

```
>>> [[sum(i * 10**(len(t) - k - 1) for k, i in enumerate(t))] for t in A]
[[123], [345], [357]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map with a list-comprehension:

```
[[int(''.join(map(str, x)))] for x in A]
# [[123], [345], [357]]
```